# Code-first - get child entity by key

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, .net-4.0, ef-code-first

I'm using Entity Framework 4.3.1 Code First and I have something similar to the following:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // get LogEntry with id x..
    }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Log> Logs { get; set; }
}

public class Log
{
    public int LogId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<LogEntry> LogEntries { get; set; }
}

public class LogEntry
{
    public int LogEntryId { get; set; }
}
```

What's the best way to get a LogEntry object given an integer LogEntryId?  Is it possible to get the entity directly without going via the `Log.LogEntries` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a reference to the context, then

```
var entry = context.Set<LogEntry>().Find(entryId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you don't have a DbSet< LogEntry > in your context?

If you did, you would be able to load it directly from the context.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Log> Logs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LogEntry> LogEntries { get; set; }
}

var logEntry = context.LogEntries.SingleOrDefault(le => le.LogEntryId == someLogEntryId);
```

Comment: This didn't occur to me - can I just add as many `DbSet<>`s as I need even though one DbSet is a 'child' of another?

Comment: Yup, you certainly can. It's pretty standard to add one for each table in your database.